Google Forms Apps Script FormSubmit not passing e.values
I have a very simple form which I would like to use Apps Script to process data from.  I have created the form and a trigger which fires an Apps Script function.  However, when I try to access the "e" parameter, the e.values is empty.  What am I doing wrong.
The code is:
function testOnFormSubmit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    Logger.log('The event object is null. This function must be called from a form submission.');
    return;
  }
  
  Logger.log('Event object: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
}

The output on form submission is:
Sep 14, 2024, 5:53:22 PM    Info    Event object: {"authMode":"FULL","response":{},"source":{},"triggerUid":"241640090"}
I have created a trigger:

I am running the form from the URL created by the Send -> Link option on the form design page.
